# How do you make a background repeat y start lower?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I'm curently workign on this [page](http://www.siteripe.com/portfolio.php) and I'm trying to make the background repeat-y from a certain height but to no avail. If you look at the link's background (bottom area); you'll see that it leaves a an ugly space there, which is ugly. The CSS is as show below

```
body {
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat -200px 0px;
}
```

Comment: your question is bit confusing can you please clarify what exactly you want to achieve, i can see the image on body. But what you want to achieve. can you please clarify so i can understand and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some mathematical thinking and experiments, the line of code below did the magic. I had to also watch where to cut it off with -1530px. Make sure you use the same background you used with the body tag.

```
html {

    background: url(images/bg.png) repeat 0px -1530px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way I'm aware of that makes the repeat skip some pixels. If I were you I would split them so the background-image of the body would be what the majority of it is now without the top. And then I would add a div to the top with these settings:

```
<div id="upperpart"></div>
```

in css:

```
#upperpart{
  background-image: url(whatever it is);
  width:100%;
  height:how high it is
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  margin-bottom: minus its height; <-- this will make everything below this div get ontop the div 
}
```